# VSCode debugger blank page and loading on launch with VS Code 1.76.1 and Chrome 111

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm facing an issue with VS Code debugger when debugging an Angular app. I have a clean Angular app generated by `ng new` command. I have added few lines of code to the `ngOnInit` function.
I want to start the chrome debugger. The browser is started successfully, but the app is not loaded. I can see only blank page, loader is still spinning, the dev console is completely empty. See the attached screenshot.
Everything was working fine few days ago. The app is started with command `npm start`, package json has the only modification - host is changed to `127.0.0.1`. The App is working properly in the normal browser window (without debug mode).

I use macOS, latest macOS Ventura version.

Could anyone help with this issue?

Here is my `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Browser:
No DOM loaded, network tab also empty (just a single request to 127.0.0.1 with no response.

[image]

I have rebooted VS Code, I have installed latest updates. Same for OS. I have tried different angular app, same result. I have also tried different port than 8080 with no luck.

Comment: We've encountered similar problems recently (since friday), on mac and on windows. I suspect antivirus interfering - any chance you run one?

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. I did mean `ng new`. 
Regarding the antivirus - I do not use antivirus on my Mac. Upgrading `vscode-js-debug` to the nightly version resolved the issue.

Comment: Myself and now three others have expeiranced this also, I've also now encountered the problem on my private laptop under compeltely different projects.

Comment: Just found, same is true for visual studio (not code). Latest updates do however seem to not address this problem. Clearing all breakpoints prior to start however did the trick.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer but I was running into the same issue with WebStorm and then similarly on VSCode. In VSCode, I removed ALL my breakpoints everywhere in the debugger session, restarted the debug session, and then it loaded just fine. After this I was then able to add breakpoints that were hit after the initial load.

I believe this has something to do with a new Chrome update.
Here's a link the issue that JetBrains has been addressing that might help explain the problem a little more, though will help you little in ultimately fixing it.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10432962465682-unable-to-debug-javascript-in-2022-3-2-ultimate-edition-with-chrome-111-on-mac-m1-arm-?page=1

Comment: Here's the answer as to why it's broken:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1421661

and here's a better fix than my previous response:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1604

Essentially, just use VSCode's nightly debugger (more frequently updated version JS debugger)

Answer (score 6):

#### Cause

This is likely caused by a recent change to Chromium's debugger. See [Issue 1421661: Missing call frames in instrumentation pause event break CDP consumers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1421661). Quoting from the issue ticket description:

> A VS Code engineer reported that the omission of call frames from instrumentation pause (https://crrev.com/c/4174085) broke VS Code because their handler does not expect empty stack trace.
>
> As this might affect other CDP consumers, we should revert and come up with a backwards compatible way of avoiding the expensive stack trace creation.

<sup>They're going to roll back the change in Chromium v112.</sup>

The `vscode-js-debug` extension maintainers are working on a recovery build that patches for the issue. See [Chrome 111 breakpoints don't work #1604](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1604).

#### Solutions

If you're getting this issue, you have a couple of options:

- [Update to VS Code 1.76.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/177012).
- Try switching to [the nightly version of the `vscode-js-debug` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly)
- Switching to VS Code insiders 1.77 may fix the issue as well.
- A number of users have reported that removing all breakpoints "resolves" the issue for them and that they can add breakpoints after removing reloading the debug session.
- <sup>Some found that the issue went away after deleting their corresponding `workspaceFolders` folder (which I'd wager solves the issue by deleting information about breakpoints, so I'd recommend **not** taking this nuclear route).</sup>

Comment: On VSCode version: 1.87.2 and Chrome v.123, switching to `JavaScript Debugger (Nightly)` solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same issue today with React using VSCode, Chrome and MacOSX. This is what I had to do to get the VSCode JavaScript Debugger working on Chrome on Mac OSX:

1. Restart your computer. it sometimes works wonders.
2. Ensure VSCode is installed in Applications folder on Mac OSX. If is
   installed in Downloads, then when attempting to update VSCode, it
   will complain about read-only volume. Go to Code > Check for
   Updates. Update to latest version.
3. Ensure your Chrome browser is updated. Go to Chrome > About Google
   Chrome. Under "About Chrome", confirm there is a message saying
   "Chrome is up to date".
4. In VSCode, go to Extensions. Search "JavaScript Debugger". With the
   latest version of VSCode, it will have "JavaScript Debugger"
   installed and enabled. Note its icon is circular yellow with a bug
   graphic. Disable it. Then Install "JavaScript Debugger (Nightly)".
   Enable "JavaScript Debugger (Nightly)". Restart VSCode.[image]
5. On the left menu, click on "Run and Debug". Choose "Add
   Configuration". Choose "Chrome: Launch". Now you will see "Launch
   Chrome" as the currently selected debugger in "RUN AND DEBUG" on the
   top.
6. Open up the generated .vscode folder (this was generated when you
   added the above configuration). Inside the launch.json file, inside
   the configuration array, ensure you have an object similar to this:

   {
   "name": "Launch Chrome",
   "request": "launch",
   "type": "chrome",
   "url": "http://localhost:3000",
   "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
   }

   Note in my case, I added the "/src" folder since that is where my app runs   from.
7. Before you attempt to run React, confirm nothing else is listening
   on the desired port:

   lsof -i tcp:3000

   If something is listening, kill it with kill -9 [process-id]
8. Then in the VSCode Terminal, run "npm start".
9. Then Run > Start Debugging in VSCode top menu. Add break points in
   VSCode and refresh the browser page and you'll notice that execution
   stops on the break points.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR for vscode:**

1. Open the "Help" menu on Windows/Linux, or the "Code" menu on macOS, and click "Check for Updates"
2. Restart VS Code after the update downloads (the "Check for Updates" button in the menu will change when it finishes download)
3. Verify you are up to date with version 1.76.1 or higher.

**More details:**

- The issue caused by a change made on chrome Version 111 (that is about to be reverted in V112).
  A fix was release by vscode (and webstorm and others as well).
  more details here:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1604
- Google said they will revert the change:
  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1421661