# VSCode 1.77 JS debugger stops on "non-existing" break points when stepping into an async function

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, vscode-debugger

When trying to debug my code, stepping into a method causes the debugger to stop at some points for no reason.
For example:

- promiseInitHookWithDestroyTracking
- promiseInitHook

(both from unknown source)

When stepping-over these "invisible" break points after 2-5 of them I usually get to the method I'm trying to debug.

I'm trying to make the debugger skip over these points.
My debug configuration I'm using contains the property: (launch.json )

```
"skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ]
```

Why is this happening, and how can I make it stop happening?

Example:

I created the following file called "test.js":

```
main();

async function main() {
    let i = await func();
    console.log(i);
}

async function func() {
    return 1;
}
```

My launch.json contains:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.js",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm adding screenshots to describe the issue.

When stopping on "let i = await func();" then stepping into I get to the followings: (look at the call stack)

[after step into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o91J6.png)

[after first step over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahfrq.png)

[after second step over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNg89.png)

[after third step over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v43VW.png)

I expect to get to the state in the last screenshot immediately after stepping into, the debugger used to do so.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the Node version, I'm using the same version for the past year.

Comment: actually ok nvm I can reproduce even with NodeJS 18. I didn't initially read the step in your screenshots. Note that regressions with various software upgrades with various software are being used together. Ex. no NodeJS upgrade but VS Code upgrade. Case in point:https://stackoverflow.com/a/75748468/11107541

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a known bug in VSCode's latest version.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179293

Answer (score 0):

#### Cause

This is a bug in the [vscode-js-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug) extension (builtin to VS Code). See the issue ticket [Error processing scopes: TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading createScope ) #1643](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1643), which is fixed by the pull request [fix: cannot read createScope of undefined #1644](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1644), where [connor4312 states](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/1644#issue-1656436358):

> This was a race that was exposed because we were waiting for scripts in the stacktrace to come in. Turns in Node.js doesn't emit Runtime.executionContextCreated for its first context.
>
> Refs [nodejs/node#47438](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47438)

This bug affects version 1.77.0 to 1.77.3 of VS Code. VS Code will bump its version of vscode-js-debug in the next release, which comes out [in early may 2023](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179293#issuecomment-1516381733)

The issue ticket is duplicated in the VS Code repository as [Javascript debugger pauses on promiseInitHookWithDestroyTracking (Unknown Source) when stepping into async function #179293](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179293).

#### Solutions

(pick one)

- You can wait until the next release of VS Code.
- You can switch to [the nightly channel of vscode-js-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#nightly-extension).
- You can downgrade to VS Code 1.76.2 (which might have its own share of bugs).