# VS Code won't step into async functions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a node.js app in VS Code and until recently the debugger has 'stepped into' async functions just fine, so that the first line of execution in the function is displayed in the editor.

For some reason, the debugger no longer does that, and instead seems to get lost in the native node code.

When I hit a breakpoint on an await call to an async function, I push F11 or use the UI step into control and nothing changes in the editor. Instead, the call stack shows the current position as 'unknown source' in emitInitNative. If I run the code, it will eventually hit a breakpoint inside the function.
[image: Call stack hitting emitInitNative]

When I step into a non-async function, the editor shows the first line of code in that function, and the call stack shows the function name.

I've no idea what's changed or how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: sounds possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76054469/11107541. Can you create a procedure to reproduce this issue (a [mre])?

Comment: what version of NodeJS are you using? Also, I can't reproduce this with a basic async IIFE with NodeJS 18.